# how to create an image file where portions of the image do not cause a printer printing the image to print anything at that location

Tags: image, printing, jpeg

I am trying to create a file which I will print on a printer (or rather someone who uses my program will do that) such that some of the file (an image actually, a jpg) does not cause the printer to print anything.  A simple case would be if I wanted the printer to print a solid rectangle around the print area, i.e. a horizontal line at the top, a horizontal line at the bottom, a solid vertical line on the right, and a solid vertical line on the left. The 4 lines together form a box.  The most sophisticated version of the problem would be to selectively for each pixel in my starting image to decide whether that pixel in the saved print file will or will not cause the printer to print something(some color) at that exact dot on the printed page (and if there IS to be a printer output at that pixel on the page then I choose what the color of that printed pixel will be).  What I want to avoid is having a white pixel cause the printer to print a white dot at that location.  If all I were ever to print would be text (instead of an image), then normal printing does this automatically (it prints text where there is text and prints nothing where there is nothing).  I want control over the "print something at a pixel" versus "print nothing at a pixel" response per pixel in an image.

Comment: I'll be doing this in C#

Comment: Do you mean to print a PNG image which is transparent in the middle, or somesuch? https://www.shutterstock.com/search/picture+frame+transparent+background

Comment: I looked at your link.  That is sort of in the area of what I'm after.  I suppose I could create a text file with a line of underscores "_" ' s to get a horizontal line and vertically stacked "|" characters to get a text file version.  Or use Photoshop or gimp or some such to make images of various sizes with various types of grids (and various grids is my basic interest).  However, I was wondering about doing this programmatically so my users could create custom sizes of this effect and to control this effect for each pixel. Users could print part of the image and draw the rest themselves

Comment: I suppose another way to ask this questions is to ask: "In a jpeg file what is the pixel value that when printed will the printer consider to be "white", i.e. the same color as the paper and thus will cause the printer to print nothing at that spot, to NOT print a white dot at that pixel thus performing the undesirable act of using up toner.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I've solved this or have come to a better understanding. Printers usually do an automatic invisible-to-the-user step of shifting from some RGB format to CMYK and unless you have an unusual printer it doesn't ever really print "white". So..255 255 255 is what I should use for a white pixel.It's a place to start experimenting anyway.